# Reference JS file in another JS file (Appium)

Tags: javascript, testing, appium

Hey guys so I'm new to `Javascript` and `Appium` but I was trying to figure out how to separate the desired capabilities into another `Javascript` file and reference it in all my test cases but I can't seem to figure it out!

config.js file

```
const android = {
    port: 4723,
desiredCapabilities: {
    platformName: "Android",
    platformVersion: "8.0",
deviceName: "VD S7 API 26",
app: "C:/Users/kristin.lau.may.hui/KonyVizEWS/temp/dcpApp/build/luaandroid/dist/luavmandroid.apk",
automationName: "UiAutomator2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to add this in separate file? Any specific use case

Comment: @demouser123 Thanks for the quick reply! It's cause I have a bunch of test cases to run and I wanted to make it easier to change if, for example, I wanted to change the emulator from an Android to an iPhone

Comment: Instead of desired capabilities, have separate config files for ios and android phones.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry its my first time using appium and JS